# How can I reverse engineer multiple existing team foundation changesets into new branches

Tags: tfs

I have tfs 2012. I am using the TFS/ALM Rangers Branching and Merging document as my guide. I am using the Basic Dual Branch Plan. I have a lot of code in changesets. No labels. I need to create 3 new branches v1.0, v2.0, v2.1. And I need to place the existing changesets into these branches. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can branch by changeset. identify the changeset numbers you want to use. right click on your source branch at the appropriate location and select Branching and merging > branch. choose specific changeset and enter the changeset number you want to be the maximum changeset for the new branch. off the top off my head I can't remember whether you have to commit the changes or whether the branch is automatically created and checked in.

Repeat the process for the other branches.

Comment: Hi justtfs, I am going to mark your answer as correct. However, for the purpose of sharing knowledge...I was going about this incorrectly. I need to solve this problem with labels and not perform branches. My reasoning, after more reading, there's no good reason to branch such that the policies for those branches are the same as the dev branch. Thanks again for your response.